# three.js - Camera on spline doesn't have a uniform speed

Tags: javascript, three.js

I used this cool codepen to have my camera follow a spline : 
https://codepen.io/wiledal/pen/WvNvEq

This works great but I want to have a uniform speed during my camera movement.
I played with all the parameters of the `CatmullRomCurve3()` function but to no avail.

In the following example you can see that it slows down at once when it reaches the curves.

Should I try to have the same intensity of points everywhere all along my spline ? If so how can I do that ?

Thank you very much.

```js
    var renderer, scene, camera, spline, camPos, camPosIndex;

                function init(){
                        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
   scene = new THREE.Scene();

   renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
   document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

   const W = window.innerWidth;
   camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, .1, 2000 );
   

   spline = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3([
    new THREE.Vector3( -70, 9 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( -20, 9 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( -13, 9 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( 13, -9 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( 20, -9 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( 70, -9 ),
   ]);


   var points = spline.getPoints(500);

   var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );

   var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color : 0xffffff } );

   // Create the final object to add to the scene
   var splineObject = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );

   scene.add(splineObject);

   camPosIndex = 0;
  }
  
  let speed = 1000;
  function update() {
   renderer.render(scene, camera);
   requestAnimationFrame(update);

   camPosIndex++;
   if (camPosIndex > speed) {
   camPosIndex = 0;
   }

   var camPos = spline.getPoint(camPosIndex / speed);
   var camRot = spline.getTangent(camPosIndex / speed);

   camera.position.x = camPos.x;
   camera.position.y = camPos.y;
   camera.position.z = camPos.z + 40; // so I can watch my spline

   camera.rotation.x = camRot.x;
   camera.rotation.y = camRot.y;
   camera.rotation.z = camRot.z;

   camera.lookAt(spline.getPoint((camPosIndex+1) / speed));
  }

  init();
  update();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try to use `.getPointAt()` instead of `.getPoint()`.

Comment: ...and `.getTangentAt()`.